# Contractability of Exotic R^4s

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Notation: $\mathbf{R}^4$ is a smooth manifold with underlying topology $(\mathbb{R})^4$; ${\mathbb{R}}^4$ is the standard smooth structure.

The two things I know best about $\mathbf{R}^4$ is that it is *locally* diffeomorphic to  $\mathbb{R} ^4$, and that it's contractible.  It's easy to see that the contraction can be acheived by a smooth map ${\mathbb{R}}^4\times I\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}^4$.

- Do I suppose correctly that the same contraction is *not* smooth as a map ${\mathbf{R}}^4\times I\rightarrow{\mathbf{R}}^4$?
- Do the exotic smooth structures have any smooth contractions?
- If not, are there *continuous* contractions $\mathbf{R}^4\times I\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^4$ within the smooth maps $\mathbf{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^4$?

Comment: What's a "contraction"? Is it a homotopy between the identity and a constant map? Any continuous map can be approximated by a smooth one, and nearby maps are homotopic, so it seems you can find a smooth homotopy between the identity and a constant map.  

Comment: @Igor: yes, a contraction is a homotopy as you describe.
You can certainly smooth any continuous map of smooth spaces; but whether the result will still be a contraction isn't clear to me.  A related issue is the failure in the smooth category of "Mazur's Swindle", that shows all spheres to be *topologically* irreducible w.r.t. connect-sum.

Comment: some guy on the street: The identity map and a constant map are both smooth, and it's an easy exercise fom Igor's statement to show that in fact all homotopic smooth maps are smoothly homotopic.  It is an exercise in milnor's Topology from a Differentiable viewpoint. 

Comment: Perhaps this question could be interpreted as follows: topologically, there is no difference between exotic-R^4 and R^4 but as manifolds, they are different.  This leads one to wonder at what point it is possible to distinguish between the two.  In particular, is it possible to distinguish exotic-R^4 and R^4 using smooth homotopy theory (i.e. homotopy theory but everything has to be smooth)?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, that would be an acceptable reaction to my line of questioning.

@Harry, Igor: perhaps I'm being dense about this, but all that's obvious to me is that there's a smoothing of a cts map $R^4\timesI\rightarrow R^4$. What's not clear is that the smoothing can be done relative to $R^4\times\{0,1\}$ that is, fixing the initial and final maps. I can almost see how to handle the final map, using a filtration of $R^4$ by bounded open sets, but I don't yet see how to deal with the initial map.  On the up-side, I think this means you can say "Yes" to the third subquestion.

Comment: $R^4\times I\rightarrow R^4$ grrr! preview comments? author edit comments?? don't mind me!

Answer (score 3):

Community wiki answer:

(Taken From Comments)

What's a "contraction"? Is it a homotopy between the identity and a constant map? Any continuous map can be approximated by a smooth one, and nearby maps are homotopic, so it seems you can find a smooth homotopy between the identity and a constant map.  The identity map and a constant map are both smooth, and it's an easy exercise from the above to show that in fact all homotopic smooth maps are smoothly homotopic (in context). It is an exercise in Milnor's Topology from a Differentiable viewpoint.